# R code for substituting values from one column to the missing values in another column

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have a data set named `one` with four columns: `D1`, `D2`, `D3` and `D4`.  `D1` is the id. `D2` has seven levels (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`). `D3` has missing data, which I want to fill by matching conditions from columns `D2` and `D4`. I am selecting values from column `D4` corresponding to four levels (`a`, `c`, `d`, `e`) of column `D2` and then replacing the missing values of column `D3` with those from `D4`.

```
D1  D2  D3  D4
1   a   .   5
2   c   12  6
3   e   .   3
4   b   .   7
5   f   .   8
6   e   .   9
7   e   11  8
8   c   .   3
9   c   52  5
10  a   .   6
11  b   4   7
12  f   .   2
13  f   .   10
14  d   .   12
15  d   .   13
16  e   .   24
17  a   1   54
18  b   2   19
19  c   5   21
```

I have following solution but it is not working. Any suggestion or help? Thanks.

```
index <- with(one, D2 %in% c('a','c','d','e'))
one$D4[index] <- one$D3[index]
one
```

Comment: The description is a bit unclear. Do you want to fill in the missing values in D3 with values in D4 if D2 is in (a, c, d, e)? That's what I understand from the first part of the question, but the later part of the question and the code are actually adding NAs to D4. Perhaps, tell us what the desired result for D3 and D4 are for rows 1, 4, and 17.

Comment: Your `.` should be NAs otherwise D3 will be strings/factors. does this do what you're wanting, I'm not sure `with(df, ifelse(is.na(D3) & D2 %in% letters[1:5], D4, D3))`

Comment: Could you provide some examples? For example, what would the first missing value in D3 be and why?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you actually do have "." in the data, and that the data are read in as characters instead of numbers/NAs, the following solution should be easier to understand than the with() call:

```
d <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, text=
"D1  D2  D3  D4
1   a   .   5
2   c   12  6
3   e   .   3
4   b   .   7
5   f   .   8
6   e   .   9
7   e   11  8
8   c   .   3
9   c   52  5
10  a   .   6
11  b   4   7
12  f   .   2
13  f   .   10
14  d   .   12
15  d   .   13
16  e   .   24
17  a   1   54
18  b   2   19
19  c   5   21"
)

indices <- d$D2 %in% c("a","c","d","e") & d$D3 == "."
d$D3[ indices ] <- d$D4[ indices ]
```

And if you actually do have NAs instead of the "." characters you could easily just use `is.na(d$D3)` as your vector indices.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `na.strings` when reading the table and then using `ifelse`. Slightly verbose but easy to understand !

```
d <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings=".", text=
                  "D1  D2  D3  D4
1   a   .   5
2   c   12  6
3   e   .   3
4   b   .   7
5   f   .   8
6   e   .   9
7   e   11  8
8   c   .   3
9   c   52  5
10  a   .   6
11  b   4   7
12  f   .   2
13  f   .   10
14  d   .   12
15  d   .   13
16  e   .   24
17  a   1   54
18  b   2   19
19  c   5   21"
)


d$D3 <- ifelse(is.na(d$D3) & (d$D2 == 'a' | d$D2 == 'c' | d$D2 == 'd' | d$D2 == 'e'), d$D4, d$D3)
```